# Как назначить имена категориям?

Tags: php

Вывожу товары по категориям по запросу catalog?cat=1

```
if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['cat']);  
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE `cat` = :cat ORDER BY `date_add` DESC");
    $sth->bindParam('cat', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $items = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

В базе категории записаны цифрами: 1, 2, 3 и так далее. На странице есть заголовок, где должно быть указано название категории:

```
<h1>Каталог <span><?php echo $row['cat']; ?></span></h1>
```

Так, естественно, выводится цифра. Вопрос: как назначить ей название?

Comment: А какие ещё есть значения в базе?

Comment: id, cat, name, description, attr-size, attr-coating, date_add

Comment: Тяните из базы значение name. $row["name"]

Comment: не пойдет такой вариант, там записано название карточки товара

Comment: Тогда постройте запрос выборки к таблице с категориями и тяните её название оттуда. Вы же конкретную структуру базы не предоставили

Comment: без изменения базы есть варианты?

Comment: Так никто её изменять не собирается... Получится что-то типа: '$id = intval($_GET['cat']);  
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `id` = :cat ORDER BY `date_add` DESC");
    $sth->bindParam('cat', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $items = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);'

Comment: таблицы с категориями отдельной нет, все, что есть в базе - это одна таблица catalog с полями, которые я скинул выше

Comment: Тогда скриптом делайте назначение переменной. Можно через `if` или `switch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$categories = [
  0 => 'Первая категория',
  1 => 'Вторая категория'
];

<h1>Каталог <span><?php $categories[$row['cat']]; ?></span></h1>
```

Comment: Странно, но вслепую ничего сказать не могу, можете показать код?

Comment: Моя ошибка, все работает, спасибо!

Comment: Не за что, рад был помочь =)

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы на странице catalog, без категории, отображался произвольный текст?